# lxml xpath() not returning what I expect

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I am following a guide (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) to scrape a website (https://www.brookfieldproperties.com/portfolio/toronto/bay-adelaide-east/) and have gone through the lxml package website and can't figure out what's going wrong.

I have this code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.brookfieldproperties.com/portfolio/toronto/bay-adelaide-east/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

floor = tree.xpath('//div[@class="column floor"]/text()')
sf = tree.xpath('//div[@class="column rsf"]/text()')
```

but **floor** and **sf** return a list of '\n\t\t\t\t' values, not an integer which you'd expect looking at the html from the actual website ("20" and "5117" in the below case):

```
<div class="availabilityWrap">
    <h3>Availabilities</h3>

    <div class="availabilityRow headerRow">
        <div class="column floor">

            <a href="/media/img/asset/pdf/BAC-ET-_20th_Floor_-_5100sf.pdf"
 target='blank'><img src="/static/images/pdf.png" class="floorPDF" />20</a>

    </div>
        <div class="column rsf">
            <p><b>5117</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column divisible">
            <p><b>yes</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column date">
            <p><b>05/01/2017</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column space">
            <p><b>Office</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column description">
            <p><b>model suite</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column rent">
            <p><b>$26.55</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Shouldn't it just be returning all text in the "column floor" div class? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
floor = tree.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="column floor"])')
```

The `div` contains the `\n\t` to get new lines and space, Those are text too, you can concatenate all the text and remove the whitespace by using `normalize-space()` function

```
In [14]: '''<div class="column floor">
...: 
...:             <a href="/media/img/asset/pdf/BAC-ET-_20th_Floor_-_5100sf.pdf"
...:  target='blank'><img src="/static/images/pdf.png" class="floorPDF" />20</a>
...: 
...:     </div>'''
Out[14]: '<div class="column floor">\n\n            <a href="/media/img/asset/pdf/BAC-ET-_20th_Floor_-_5100sf.pdf"\n target=\'blank\'><img src="/static/images/pdf.png" class="floorPDF" />20</a>\n\n    </div>'
```

EDIT:

```
for div in tree.xpath('//div[@class="column floor"]'):
    print(div.xpath('normalize-space(.)')) # `.` means current node
```

Comment: Thanks! That partially worked; it pulled the first instance of text in a div class named "column floor" but there are many others in the page that I was hoping to include in the list. Any ideas?